Using Brightway REST API to Obtain Carbon Footprint and Water Depletion Values for Materials
I am currently working on a project where I need to access carbon footprint and water depletion values for various materials. I have been exploring the Brightway REST API as a potential solution for retrieving this data. However, I'm unsure about the specific steps to achieve this. Could someone please provide guidance on how to utilize the Brightway REST API effectively to obtain carbon footprint and water depletion values for different materials? Any insights, code examples, or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I'm currently in the research phase of a project where I need to calculate the carbon footprint and water depletion values for various materials. Rather than creating my own ELCD (European Life Cycle Database) for this purpose, I'm exploring the possibility of using a ready-made backend or API solution. My goal is to retrieve the core values of this Life Cycle Inventory (LCI) data and then perform calculations based on the amount of each material, without factoring in transportation, pre-processing, or post-processing. Does anyone have recommendations for suitable backends or APIs that can provide this functionality? Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Where is the Brightway REST API hosted? The hosting provider should have all the documentation you need to send HTTP requests.

I saw your question, so I decided to push a project I had sitting on my computer for a while to GitHub.
https://github.com/Haitham-ghaida/bw25fastapi
I have instructions on how to use it in the readme file.
It should be easy to set up. Preferably, you have access to ecoinvent databases.
There is still a lot of functionality missing, but you can use it with other Brightway frameworks to extend it.

wtf. that sounds amazing! Thanks, Afriend, I will inspect it as soon as possible! Also thank you Bill, I thought I could ask for the documentation / this here.
Im not sure if persons are allowed to offer open https if they don't fill the Database with their Datasets, due to only ELCD and e.g. Agribalyse being Open Source, but there's also the ecospold2 format whats widely used by eco-invent, where you need a license.

No problem ;) Let me know if there are any specific features to make it more useful for you and I will try to prioritize them.
